# about featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am Seonhyang.
I have my own blog which has been for a year.
However I got a problem 2 weeks ago.
When I uploaded the featured image for a post, an error occurred that made all my posts of its category disappeared and was blocked. 
Also there is a note on the screen like this;

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 40632320) (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home3/nabi/public_html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1438

I have tried to fix this problem in many ways.
I have tried to resize the featured image to small one and put different pictures and publish another new post with other featured images.
But all I have done for fixing the problem did not work.

More precisely I can not upload any post more with featured image which means publishing a post without featured image is possible.

I have no idea with this problem now and really need your help to turn it back to normal.

Please answer my question asap and I would appreciate that.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you have used a lot of posts & category. So, Once you update/add the post then recursion will occur. So, I suggest you should use a cache plugin.
2. Try to put ini_set( 'memory_limit', '512M'); in wp-config header file & check it.